# Taking screenshots is suddenly very slow

Tags: 20.04, mate, ubuntu-mate, screenshot

Lately, I have noticed that `mate-screenshot` has become very slow. I keep up with the 20.04 LTS updates, and I don't know what packages were updated recently that caused this.

Interestingly, the latency seems to be not between starting the program (e.g. via the <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> key or the `mate-screen` command) and taking the screenshot; rather, the big lag (~30 seconds) is between taking the screenshot, and popping up the window to save or discard it. I have validated this observation by taking a screenshot of a window showing a clock.

Running`mate-screenshot` in `strace`, it is stuck on a `poll` call:

```
poll([{fd=12, events=POLLIN}], 1, 25000
```

The full `strace` log starting at the opening of this file descriptor all the way to the stall, is as follows:

```
eventfd2(0, EFD_CLOEXEC|EFD_NONBLOCK)   = 12
write(12, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)        = 8
write(8, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8)         = 8
futex(0x7f2e10013000, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
futex(0x7f2e10012d90, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
futex(0x55e608d13698, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
poll([{fd=12, events=POLLIN}], 1, 25000) = 1 ([{fd=12, revents=POLLIN}])
read(12, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16)        = 8
poll([{fd=12, events=POLLIN}], 1, 25000) = ...
```

What could be causing this slowdown, and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: Unfortunately, a reboot following an accidental killing of `dbus-daemon` has made this problem go away, so I have no way of providing additional logs / measurements / observations :( Maybe it will start happening agan?